# how to net stop server from a batch file when there are open connections?

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

I've found a few scripts here and elsewhere to start/stop windows services, locally or remotely, using net, sc, psservices, but none covers the case of force stopping the server service when the system replies that there are open connections.

Anyone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch script runs the powershell `Stop-Service` cmdlet and `uses the -force` parameter.  It will stop the service regardless of open connections, tested on Terminal Services with open RDP session.

```
@ECHO OFF
start /b /wait powershell.exe -command "Stop-Service -name TermService -force;$STATUS = (Get-Service termservice).status;Write-Host `"Termservice is $STATUS`""
PAUSE
```

Comment: Seems to work with '-name server' which is what I wanted.  Need to find out if all my XP boxes have powershell installed.  Thanks! Not sure how to mark this as answer, system doesn't let me up arrow.

Comment: there is a thing below the up arrow that kinda looks like a chevron, if you click that it will turn green.  That is how to accept an answer.  Good luck